# Shortcuts in Windows XP start menu disappeared

Tags: windows-xp, user-accounts, start-menu

I have a Windows XP Professional. I have a problem with default IE6. I upgraded to IE7 but still had the problem. Then, I used revo uninstaller to uninstall IE7 and back to IE6. I did choose revo uninstaller's scan mode to be the one that'd make in-depth scan of registry. (Sorry, I dont remember the exact term)

The problem was solved. But almost all the shortcuts in Start > Programs is gone for all the user accounts such as bob, john in that computer.

As I checked, they are not really gone. I can still see those shortcuts in "C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Start menu\Programs". But they do not appear anymore in other users start menu. Is my IE7 removal and the problem related? Or how do I fix the current problem?

I tried to do system restore as revo uninstaller said it created a restore point when I ran it. But shortcut for system restore in start menu also gone. I booted from safe mode and try to run rrstrui.exe from command line, it wont load. Please help me. I actually have no idea how to solve this. Thanks.

Comment: are they hidden?

Comment: no, they arent.